# How to resize only one side of NSWIndow programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow

From the Apple documentation, we can modify the resizing value(multipliers)
by assigning new values to ResizeIncrements.

But The minimum value is 1 so, I was wondering if resizing only one side (only Width or only Height at a time) is possible.

I've tried to use callback, resetting the size of the NSWindow each time the user drag to resize it, but it's not working.

Edit:

To be more specific, I'd like to know if restricting the resizing option to only one side is possible.

Comment: [The docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419390-resizeincrements?language=objc) say *Whatever the current resizing increments, you can set an NSWindow object’s size to any height and width programmatically.*  However it's not clear if you mean set only width/height of window pro grammatically or restrict the user's resizing to width or height only.

Comment: restrict the user's resizing to width or to height only was the question, I'll modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes simply override [`windowWillResize:size:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowdelegate/1419292-windowwillresize?language=objc) and return whatever value you want to allow.

I don't believe `resizeIncrements` will affect this; that just sets the increments to allow but the window delegate will have the final say.